# Making a single div boxed layout with responsive images

Tags: wordpress, dreamweaver

So, I am looking to make this boxed layout (a table?) as seen as an example on this site (the 5 pictures underneath "Our Story"): https://blacktailnyc.com/

This is my site and what I have so far (5 pictures underneath the "reserve now" button): http://www.ennebicommunications.com/havana/

Am I going to have to do a combo of CSS3 and image resizing?

Answer (score -1):

I think flexbox will get the job done right.